# Have you solved triangulation based on lat/long pairs and then output a US postal code?

Tags: postgresql, centroid

I have a postgres table with a person_id, and the locations each person has visited. Tall, three column table (**pid, latitude, longitude**). A person will have multiple rows if they went to more than one location.

Based on the places each person has visited, I would like to find the geographic center and then translate that center into a US postal code. Weighting is fine (centroid of multipoint), but can live without. End result would be one postal_code per pid.

Not super familiar with postgis commands in postgres, and still haven't found the right method. Am open to other alternatives (R, py) but would prefer to keep it in postgres. Would love to hear if you have solved this.

Comment: One option is to simply take the average of the latitude and the average longitude while grouping by PID and do a postal code lookup with them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use PostGIS [`ST_GeometricMedian`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_GeometricMedian.html) for this purpose. You would have to `st_collect` the aggregated points first.

Once you have the central point, you can check its postal code using your favorite geocoder or a polygon layer of your own.

Changing the doc example to use multiple points instead of one multipoint we get

```
WITH test(pid,geom) AS (values 
   (1,'POINT(0 0)'::geometry),
   (1,'POINT(1 1)'::geometry),
   (1,'POINT(2 2)'::geometry),
   (1,'POINT(200 200)'::geometry))
SELECT
  ST_AsText(ST_Centroid(st_collect(geom))) centroid,
  ST_AsText(ST_GeometricMedian(st_collect(geom))) median
FROM test
GROUP BY pid;

      centroid      |                 median
--------------------+----------------------------------------
 POINT(50.75 50.75) | POINT(1.9761550281255 1.9761550281255)
```